# local.xml Varnish ESI policy

Tags: magento-1.9, local.xml, varnish

I am using Ultimo theme for my Magento (1.9.2.1) website. How can I merge the Varnish ESI xml with the theme's current local.xml file?

For example for turpentine_esi.xml the header is

```
    <reference name="header">
        <action method="setEsiOptions">
            <params>
                <access>private</access>
                <flush_events>
                    <wishlist_item_save_after/>
                    <wishlist_item_delete_after/>
                    <sales_quote_save_after/>
                </flush_events>
            </params>
        </action>
    </reference>
```

and in the theme local.xml the header is

```
        <reference name="header">

        <!-- Mini cart -->
        <block type="checkout/cart_sidebar" name="cart_sidebar" template="checkout/cart/mini.phtml" before="-">
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>simple</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>grouped</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_grouped</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <action method="addItemRender"><type>configurable</type><block>checkout/cart_item_renderer_configurable</block><template>checkout/cart/sidebar/default.phtml</template></action>
            <block type="core/text_list" name="cart_sidebar.extra_actions" as="extra_actions" translate="label" module="checkout">
                <label>Shopping Cart Sidebar Extra Actions</label>
            </block>
            <block type="cms/block" name="block_mini_cart_above_products">
                <action method="setBlockId"><block_id>block_mini_cart_above_products</block_id></action>
            </block>
        </block>


    </reference>
```

Comment: ?? your header will be hole punched, no matter what local.xml has...

Comment: So haw can I keep the header same and implement esi options? @ADM

Comment: turpentine_esi.xml = varnish cache; local.xml = magento design;  what else you need???

Answer (score 1):

Turpentine will read both your `local.xml` file as well as `turpentine_esi.xml` - any `local.xml` settings will override the default settings in `turpentine_esi.xml`.

So, if you don't specify anything in `local.xml`, the policies set in `turpentine_esi.xml` will be applied to your header. There is no need to "merge" the two files.